# Fancybox popup not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, fancybox

I have added this script for fancybox popup. But it is not working.

It is working on other page but don't know what is the problem in this page, there is much more JavaScript for other functionality, may be this is the reason, but when in console, there's no error!

```
<table id="tb1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7" style="width:99%;border:solid 1px#c0bebe;min-width:550px;height:auto;font-family:arial;font-size:11px;margin-left: 6px;border-bottom: none;">
    <tr class="heads tr_check" height="44px">
        <th style="padding-left:15px;width:5%">Date</th>
        <th style="padding-left:15px;width:5%">From</th>
        <th style="padding-left:15px;width:5%">Mode</th>
        <th style="padding-left:15px;width:40%">Message</th>
        <th style="padding-left:15px;width:10%;border-right: medium none;">Document</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $msgMngResult = getMessagesForEdit($_GET['projectid']);
    if(mysql_num_rows($msgMngResult)>0) {
        while($msgMngtaskDtlsRow = mysql_fetch_array($msgMngResult)) {  
            if($msgMngtaskDtlsRow['message_from']=='Client') {
                $bgcolor = "background-color:#F8E0EC";
            } else {
                $bgcolor = "background-color:#E7FFD6";
            }
            $id = $msgMngtaskDtlsRow['id'];
            $msgres = getMsgDoc($id);
            ?>
            <tr height="44px" class="tr_check">
                <td style="padding-left:15px;<?php echo $bgcolor;?>"><?php echo $msgMngtaskDtlsRow['msg_date'];?></td>
                <td style="padding-left:15px;<?php echo $bgcolor;?>"><?php echo $msgMngtaskDtlsRow['message_from'];?></td>
                <td style="padding-left:15px;<?php echo $bgcolor;?>"><?php echo $msgMngtaskDtlsRow['message_mode'];?></td>
                <td style="padding-left:15px;<?php echo $bgcolor;?>"><?php echo substr($msgMngtaskDtlsRow['message'],0,100);?><a href="#divForm<?php echo $id;?>" id="messages<?php echo $id;?>" class="fmsg" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" style="color:blue;float: right;">Read More..</a></td>
                <div id="divForm<?php echo $id;?>" class="fancybox" style="display:none;">
                    <p><?php echo $msgMngtaskDtlsRow['message'];?></p>
                </div>
                <td style="border-right: medium none;padding-left:15px;<?php echo $bgcolor;?>">
                    <?php while($res = mysql_fetch_array($msgres)) {
                        echo "<br/><a href='".PROJECT_FILE_PATH.$msg_doc."/".$res['message_docs']."' target='_blank' style='color:blue;text-decoration: underline;'>".$res['message_docs']."</a><br/>"; 
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hidetr tr_check acctr_<?php echo $msgMngtaskDtlsRow['id']; ?>" ><td colspan="8" style="border-right:0px;"></td></tr>
        <?php
        }
    } else { ?>
        <tr height="44px" class="tr_check">
            <td align="center" colspan="12">
                <div id="err"><div id="errormsg" class="no-record"><strong> No Records Found </strong></div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    } ?>
</table>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabber.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paddRow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addUnitRow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script>
    $('.fmsg').live('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
        $("#"+id).fancybox({
            'width':800,
            'height':450,
            'autoSize' : false,
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'float'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Sometimes it shows - `ement.prop is not defined`.

It appears often.

Comment: would you make a snippet? it would be easier to understand

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to create snippet. i'm newbie here.

Comment: if it was only JS, snippet would help.. PHP wouldnt work i guess.. :)

Comment: ok, but there is no answer for this question yet. :(

Comment: Thnx @Prashanth for editing.

Comment: hope you find an answer soon.. BTW i did not find any `ement.prop` in the code...

Comment: As far as I can quickly see, you are including jQuery twice (most likely triggering a js error). A single instance would be enough and make sure it is loaded **before** any plugin to avoid hoisting issues